# Cant open page while uploading to my own website

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can't open a second page from my own ASP.NET MVC website when the first page is uploading a file. The first page seems blocking the second one and I Have to wait it finish uploading or clear the website cookies before able to open another page.

HOw to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Thinks you need upload file asynchronous..

Comment: Do your pages share some common resource? I.e. do your controllers call some shared resource which could be blocked by a file upload?

Comment: Hi i doubt its because of sharing resource. BEcause the first page when doing upload does not even yet hit the MVC's action because the stream is still transfering to IIS level, so the MVC's action is not yet call and won't cause the lock to the second page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems is because ASP.NET poor session design, when you use a code behind MVC Action that has session enable, and call the action sending a huge chunk of data, such as when doing upload, the session will be locked by ASP.NET

WHen the session is locked, when you request another MVC Action that has session in it, the request will be queued and won't be processed until the previous MVC Action that is locking the session release it. THis is a big design fault on ASP.NET that I found out recently

That's why many big websites disable default ASP.NET session by using SessionStateAttribute

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehaviour.Disabled)]
```

AND this is also a fault with Microsoft because the attribute only accepted by CLass not Method, as thus you have to do work around as explained in this URL [Apply session state behavior per action](http://sapoval.org/per-action-custom-sessionstateattribute)

Seeing this I am really worry that ASP.NET technology is the correct technology I am choosing for my website, my effort and learning time in this technology will be blasted because of all this limitation done by Microsoft.

Furthermore, implementing ajax or other asynchronous thing such as Threading, won't help the problems, as because when the thread is called from an Action that has session enable, another action that also has session enabled will be queued too.